# Android error at Intent command

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I'm having trouble with my code. When I click on the Title "New Profile" a new Activity has to start but when I click, an alert is shown: "*Unfortunately %AppName% has stopped.*".

Here is log of Android Monitor

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-17 01:19:54.545 2568-2568/com.example.felipe.myappproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.felipe.myappproject, PID: 2568
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.felipe.myappproject/com.example.felipe.myappproject.NewProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
       at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
       at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4449)
       at com.example.felipe.myappproject.NewProfileActivity.<init>(NewProfileActivity.java:14)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

And here my NewProfileActivity.java

```
public class NewProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText profile, password, confirmpass;
        Intent insert = new Intent(NewProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_profile);
        }

        public void backMain(View v){

            startActivity(back);

        }

        public void insertData(View v) {

            profile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileName);
            password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            confirmpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);

            insert.putExtra("profile", profile.getText().toString());
            insert.putExtra("password", password.getText().toString());
            insert.putExtra("profile", confirmpass.getText().toString());

            compare(password.getText().toString(), confirmpass.getText().toString());
        }

        public void compare(String x, String y){

            final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewProfileActivity.this).create();

            if(x.equals(y)){
                alert.setTitle("New Profile!");
                alert.setMessage("Profile "+profile+" registered");
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );
                startActivity(insert);
            } else {
                alert.setTitle("Ops...");
                alert.setMessage("Passwords don't macth");
                alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't find what I am doing wrong. I tried to simplify the code by removing everything except the **"public void backMain(View v)"** but I still get the same problem.

Comment: You can't instantiate `Intent`s there. Just create them right before you need them in your methods.

Comment: The code works with @MikeM. 's resoltion. Thanks a lot, I don't realize that the Intent was outside my methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MikeM's comment, you are initializing your `Intent` at the very beginning, where even the class that you are passing as a parameter isn't fully initialized yet.

You should simply just initialize right before you would use it like so:

```
public class NewProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText profile, password, confirmpass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_profile);
    }

    public void backMain(View v) {
        // startActivity(back);
    }

    public void insertData(View v) {

        profile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profileName);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        confirmpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirmPassword);

        compare(password.getText().toString(), confirmpass.getText().toString());
    }

    public void compare(String x, String y) {

        final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewProfileActivity.this).create();

        if (x.equals(y)) {
            alert.setTitle("New Profile!");
            alert.setMessage("Profile " + profile + " registered");
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            );
            // CODES Transferred here ====
            Intent insert = new Intent(NewProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

            insert.putExtra("profile", profile.getText().toString());
            insert.putExtra("password", password.getText().toString());
            insert.putExtra("profile", confirmpass.getText().toString());
            // CODES Transferred here ====
            startActivity(insert);
        } else {
            alert.setTitle("Ops...");
            alert.setMessage("Passwords don't macth");
            alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers! :D